# RootTools.jar and OneSignal SDK creates duplicate entry error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0, onesignal, roottools

I have android project that include RootTools.jar, it was run without any problem, but when I add OneSignal SDk by following this guide:
[Android SDK Installation (Android Studio)](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-studio-sdk-installation) I got error when try to run it:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/stericson/RootTools/internal/RootToolsInternalMethods.class
```

I tried to debug it and got this:

> 10:36:07.391 [DEBUG] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMerger] addJar(C:\Apps\SatpolApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.onesignal\OneSignal\2.1.2\jars\classes.jar): entry com/onesignal/TrackGooglePurchase.class
>
> 10:36:07.399 [DEBUG]
> [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMerger] ad
> dJar(C:\Apps\SatpolApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.onesignal\OneSignal\2.1.2\jars\classes.jar): entry
> com/stericson/RootTools/internal/RootToolsInternalMethods.class
>
> 10:36:08.363 [DEBUG]
> [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter]
> Finished executing task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'
>
> 10:36:08.370 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger]
> :app:transformCl assesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

So I found out that OneSignal jar has com/stericson/RootTools/internal/RootToolsInternalMethods.class which cause the duplicate entry error since I already include RootTools.jar.

What I want to ask is how I exclude the "com/stericson/RootTools/internal/RootToolsInternalMethods.class" from OneSignal jar while keep it functioning?

Comment: what is the result of `gradle dependencies`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class was baked into the .jar in the .aar file. The class name conflict is now resolved in version [2.1.3](https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases/tag/2.1.3) of the OneSignal Android SDK.